# How to send multiple files to backend API using angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, api, httprequest, backend

On my site created with Angular I have a contact form that takes as input: "name", "surname", "email", "message" and optionally one or more files and (via an API that connects to a backend via a call Http post) send an email.

This is the contact form:

```
      <form [formGroup]="form" >

        <label for="nome">First name</label>
        <input  class="" type="text" id="name" placeholder="Name"  formControlName="name">

        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="surname">Last name</label>
        <input  class="" type="text" id="surname" placeholder="Surname"  formControlName="surname">

        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input  class="" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Your email"   formControlName="email" >

        <br>
        <br>

        <label for="message">Message</label>
        <textarea  class="" id="message" rows="5"  formControlName="message"></textarea>

        <br>

        <input type="file" name="upload1" id="upload1" class="upload" (change)="onChange($any($event).target.files);" multiple  accept=".pdf,.jpg,.jpeg,.png,.doc,.docx,.txt" formControlName="file">
        <label for="upload1">
          <svg class="icon icon-sm" aria-hidden="true"><use href="../assets/bootstrap-italia/svg/sprite.svg#it-upload"></use></svg>
          <span>Add attachments</span>
        </label>

        
        <br>

        <button type="submit" class="btn mb-5 btn-primary btn-lg px-5" [disabled]="!form.valid" (click)="sendMail();">SEND</button>


      </form>
```

I created an array of files in this way:

```
  onChange(event){
    for (let i = 0; i < event.length; i++) {
      this.attachments.push(event[i]);
    }
  }
```

And this is the http post request:

```
  sendMail(){
    this.http.post("mybackendURL",{
      first_name : this.form.controls['name'].value,
      last_name : this.form.controls['surname'].value,
      from : this.form.controls['email'].value,
      subject : "Contact",
      message : this.form.controls['message'].value,
      attachment : ???????????
    }).subscribe(res =>{
      return res;
    })
  }
```

NOW : The request is sent correctly to the backend BUT if I insert files they are not read, and the backend receives a list of empty objects, while all the other fields (name, surname, email and message) are filled in correctly.

How can I pass the files to the backend correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `FormData` to do that :

```js
const formData = new FormData();

formData.set('your filename', theFileObject);
```

Only form data can send files through HTTP. It also support "primitive" values such as strings and such, so you can send your whole form with it.